# install beautiful soup specifically in python3.5

Tags: apt, server, system-installation, python

I have three versions of python `python2.7`, `python3.5` , `python3.4` i am trying to run the django server and it is giving me error of `Htmlparser` so the beautiful soup is not configured properly.

I have noticed that in the `dist-packages` of 3.5 it is not there while beautiful soup is in the `python3.4`. When i tried to upgrade it says that already install in `python3.4`.

i have tried `pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4` 
still it gives me error

> Requirement already up-to-date: beautifulsoup4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (4.6.3)

While my current version of `python` is `python3.5.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run `pip` as module of the Python version you want, instead of the `pip` command, which can point to any Python version, depending on what was installed last and how:

```
python3.5 -m pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
```